# Is it possible to use the configuration of an application server from another server?

Tags: java, jboss, server, websphere

This is a weird situation. I run a main application in an application server(say WAS) and a sub application in another server (say JBoss). Now , the sub application needs to use the configuration made in the main application server(for example , sub application needs to use the ObjectPoolManager configuration made in WAS from JBoss). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can of course write some kind of adapter, which reads the WAS configuration and translates it to the JBoss format and sets the JBoss configuration. However, i think the cost-benefit-factor for such a development is very very bad.